# Python - Replace years by Index/Value

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a question. I have a structured numpy array with a year count like this one:

```
array_start([(2020),
(2020),
(2021),
(2021),
dtype=[('year', '<i8')])
```

In this example, 2020 is the earliest year, but this might change, so I can't really use this year hard coded or use a dictionairy. I would like to replace the year column by count / index like this:

```
array_desired_1([(1),
(1),
(2),
(2),
dtype=[('year', '<i8')])
```

or alternatively:

```
array_desired_2([(1, 2020),
(1, 2020),
(2, 2021),
(2, 2021),
dtype=[('year', '<i8'), ('index', '<i8')])
```

The only thing that I got so far is finding a way to get the earliest year:

```
earlies_year_mask = array_start['year'] == np.amin(array_start['year'])
```

But I don't think I'm on the right track wih this... could someone help me? It should be pretty easy but I can't get to the right answer..

Comment: Does the index ordering matter? As in, can 2020 be `2` and 2021 be `1`?

Comment: yes  good point: the order is very important.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but between the use of `df` and accessing `df.year` as an attribute, it seems like you're actually working with a `pandas` `DataFrame` (or maybe a `Series`?).

If it's a `DataFrame`, I'm going to guess `year` is a column from the vertical orientation, in which case you can can do this:

`df.year = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)`

If it's a `Series`, you could do this:

`df = pd.Series(df.index + 1)`

=============

Edit:

ah, I think I see what you're saying now. How about this (similar solution)?

`array_start['year'] = np.arange(1, array_start.shape[0] + 1)`

Comment: Hi, ah sorry no it reaylly is a numpy arra, I will edit the code a bit

Comment: hmm, when I do this, it just replaces the year with an index, different for every row like this: array([(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
dtype=[('year', '<i8')]). While, what I'm actually after is that all 2020 years are replaced with 1, 2021 are replaced with 2 etc. like this: array([(1),
(1),
(2),
(2),
dtype=[('year', '<i8')]).

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found my answer! :

```
year_count = 1

for year in np.unique(array_start['year']):
    array_start['year'][array_start['year'] == year] = year_count
    year_count = year_count + 1
```

any answers without a loop or which are more efficient are still very welcome :)